# Correct conditions for quickselect

Tags: java, quicksort, quickselect

I am implementing the quick-select algorithm to get the `k`th element in an array, and I am stuck at a place where I don't know how to resolve. Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[]{7,6,5,4,3,2,1}; 
    int k = 4;
    quickSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1, k);
    return arr[k];
}

private static void quickSelect(int[] nums, int start, int end, int k) {
    if (start < end) {
        int partitionIndex = getPartitionIndex(nums, start, end);
        if (partitionIndex == k) {
            return;
        }
        quickSelect(nums, start, partitionIndex - 1, k);
        quickSelect(nums, partitionIndex + 1, end, k);
    }
}

private int getPartitionIndex(int[] nums, int start, int end) {
    int pivot = nums[end];
    int index = start;
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        int current = nums[i];
        if (current < pivot) {
            swap(nums, index, i);
            index++;
        }
    }
    swap(nums, index, end);
    return index;
}

private void swap(int[] nums, int i, int j) {
    if (i == j) {
        return;
    }
    nums[i] = nums[i] ^ nums[j];
    nums[j] = nums[i] ^ nums[j];
    nums[i] = nums[i] ^ nums[j];
}
```

Sure, if I remove these lines:

```
        if (partitionIndex == k) {
            return;
        }
```

It becomes quicksort and works fine. And I understand why it's not working, it is since the array I am getting from 0 to k might not be sorted as I return at the above condition. But I am not able to find the right conditions where I sort only the first k elements in the array and leave out the rest, so that I don't do any extra work. I've looked at some implementations online and spent some time on the above, but not able to figure it out, so reaching out for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If k < partitionIndex, only check the left partition, else only check the right partition.

```
        if (k < partitionIndex)
            quickSelect(nums, start, partitionIndex - 1, k);
        else
            quickSelect(nums, partitionIndex + 1, end, k);
```